# How to automatically encrypt S3 access logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kms

Is it possible to configure S3 to encrypt the access logs with a specific CMK from the Key Management System before storing it back to the designated log destination on S3?

I would like to encrypt the logs to add an additional layer of security to the log data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible. You could build a system that encrypts the logs as soon as they are written using SNS and Lambda, but this is not available out of the box.